# 64-bit (x64/amd64) git client for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, git

Is there a 64-bit command-line git client for windows (with precompiled binaries)?

I have been using msysGit (32-bit) but it will not store files larger than 2GB. I hear that this restriction does not apply to 64-bit git clients. If there is a way to store files >= 2gb using 32bit git that would work as well...

Comment: There is cygwin, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't have precompiled git binary. in new cygwin its not hard to compile things tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

64-bit version at [msysgit](http://msysgit.github.io/) worked for me, it's been called "beta" for years but works fine.

Comment: @Grynn: A featured beta version seems to be available, last update was last month.

Comment: It is in pre-alpha atm -- "A preview to get people interested in working on the 64-bit build. The test suite reported 31 failed tests. So if it breaks for you or eats your little children: you have been warned."  I'm not sure I would trust my repo to a build that fails unit tests...

Answer (score 0):

Check out GitHub for Windows: http://windows.github.com/
I haven't used it (I'm a Mac user) but it looks great and I've heard a lot of positive feedback.

As for 64-bit, I don't see anything in it's description that would give a definitive answer. I'll let you try that out and see.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I use both cygwin and msysgit.  Cygwin provides 64-bit binaries for git, but it's UNIX compatibility layer sometimes causes problems with the files when they are in the working copy.  A problem I have hit is if I had an ".exe" and a file with no extension (for UNIX) in the same folder with the same base name, it will say the file already exists.

I use the 64-bit binary primarily to do an `git svn clone` of an existing SVN repository which had large check-ins at one point and the 32-bit msysgit binaries just don't work with it.

However, once I get the repository loaded, I use the 32-bit msysgit because it integrates with Windows better.